# Is it possible to use OpenSlide on Google Colab?

Tags: google-colaboratory, openslide

I need to split a tif image in patches. Images are in a gigapixel resolution and it takes really long on my machine.

Is it possible to use OpenSlide on Google Collaboratory?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is really easy.
Just ran this:

```
!apt update && apt install -y openslide-tools
!pip install openslide-python
```

Comment: were you able to use deepzoom in colab? i get an error that says it can't find openslide module

Comment: I keep getting the daunting error message: TileSourceException: No available tilesource for exapmle_image.ndpi although I know that this file is there and I could open it in other saturn (not google collaboration) instances. Anybody has an idea why?